# back button from hierachical Setting Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, settings

I have a hierarchical Setting Activity that different setting fragments. I would like the back button in the top bar to navigate back to the previous setting menu AND back to the home activity when clicked from the root setting menu.

I can only manage to do either one behaviour or the other, but not both.

If I use :

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.demo.app.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

It always goes back to my home page rather than going back to the previous settings screen.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I can handle it like that in my SettingsActivity :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if(this.getTitle().equals(R.string.settings_header)){ // here put the title of the root
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```